# Why is the binding energy per nucleon of helium-3 less than that of helium-4?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

I'd guess it has to do with the structure of helium-3 allowing for greater Coulomb repulsion between the protons, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Coulomb energy goes like $Z(Z-1)$, so it's typically a very small effect for light nuclei. The Coulomb energy would be responsible for the difference in binding energy between 3He and 3H.

In general, even-even nuclei are always more bound than odd nuclei. This is due to pairing.

Apart from pairing, one can usually predict nuclear binding energies quite well at a quantitative level by considering them to be the sum of a liquid-drop energy and a shell correction (Strutinsky 1968). The shell correction for <sup>4</sup>He is large, because it's doubly magic. (I don't actually know if the Strutinsky works well for such light nuclei, but it's definitely good enough to give a correct qualitative explanation.)

> “Shells” in deformed nuclei. V. M. Strutinsky, [*Nucl. Phys. A* **122** no. 1 (1968) pp. 1-33](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0375-9474(68)90699-4).
>
> See also: Curvature Correction in the Strutinsky's Method. P. Salamon, A. T. Kruppa. [*J. Phys. G: Nucl. Part. Phys.* **37** no. 10 (2010) 105106](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0954-3899/37/10/105106). [arXiv:1004.0079](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0079). (A variation on the technique, describes the technique itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Helium-3 has less of a binding energy because the strong force is less as there are less nucleons. Not only that the electromagnetic force sort of wins over slightly. This is because in Helium-3 there are 2 protons and one neutron. However in Helium-4 there are 2 protons and also 2 neutrons. Also all the spins for the nucleons are perfect.

-one spin up proton

-one spin down proton

-one spin up neutron

-one spin down neutron

Also more nucleons means stronger strong force especially up to Iron.